# How to typeset converge in probability in lyx or latex?

Tags: lyx

I'm a new user for lyx, and I am wondering how you can put the `p` above that right arrow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can insert the LaTeX command `overset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
a \overset{p}{\to} b
\]
\end{document}
```

Just insert it as red text.

Answer (score 8):

This is *natively* possible in LyX (as many other math commands!).

Start math mode (e.g., by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>). Then type

`\overset` + <kbd>space</kbd> + `\to` + <kbd>space</kbd> + <kbd>up (cursor key)</kbd> + `p` + <kbd>space</kbd>

This produces [image: overset-to].

Comment: Why CW? This perfectly answers the OPs question.

Comment: Yes, but "how to do it in LyX" really is the point here. You answered it and deserve the rep; the chance (and necessity) for somebody else to contribute further to this answer is pretty low, so CW doesn't make a lot of sense here.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, changed! I'll keep this in mind for future...